# How to plot dual cone of a given conical domain?

Tags: plotting

If $K$ is a given cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which passes through origin, the dual cone $K^*$ is defined as $K^*=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3 \big| \,\,  \mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}\ge 0  \,\, \forall y\in K\}$.

Given a cone, e.g., $K=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,\,\big|\,\, xy-z^2\ge 0\}$, how do I plot its dual cone $K^*$, using RegionPlot3d or ContourPlot3d?

Comment: `ImplicitRegion`, `DiscretizeRegion`, `RegionPlot`, and `ConvexHull` might be relevant here.

Comment: Could you please be more specific, as in, how to use this functions?

Comment: @Ayan Mathematica has an extensive documentation center. In a first step, you can read all pages to the function Henrik suggested. Then, you can try to change some of the examples to meet your situation and see how this works. If you still run into problems, show us what you have tried so far by editing this question and vote for re-opening if the current answer doesn't help you. At the moment, your question does not show anything you have already tried.

Comment: Btw., the dual cone of this problem should consist of a single point: $K^* = \{0\}$, since $K = - K$.

Answer (score 1):

The cone K can be plotted as

```
RegionPlot3D[x y - z^2 >=   0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1 , 1}, {z, -1, 1},MaxRecursion -> 5, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z} ]
```

[image]

The dual cone might be plotted in the same we using the additional conditions...

Comment: I have already done this. What about the dual cone $K^*$?

Comment: Why didn't you show your efforts? This would ease up answering!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `ForAll`.
As pointed out by Henrik Schumacher, for your particular example $K^*=\{0\}$ since $K=-K$. Thus, I will show how to plot the dual cone one the freely chosen set
$x\geq0$, $y\geq0$ and $x+y\leq5$.

The function `ForAll` when given three parameters,
`ForAll[{x1,...xn},cond,expr]`
states that `expr` is true for all `xi` satisfying the condition `cond`.
`Resolve` or `Reduce` then solves such systems. Thus, a MWE looks like

```
cone = x>=0 && y>=0 && x+y<=5
dual = Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, cone, px x + py y <= 0], {px, py}]
RegionPlot[cone, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
RegionPlot[dual, {px, -10, 10}, {py, -10, 10}]
```